# the meaning of 'but just so'

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a newspaper article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/opinion/trans-rights-bill-1.4113455)

At the end there it says 'but just so'. What does it mean?

> A TERF is, apparently, a "trans-exclusionary radical feminist,"
>   someone belonging to "that group of feminists that claims that trans
>   women aren't really women, as biological determinism is only a fallacy
>   when it's used against them, not when they use it against others."
>
> Well. I'm not keen on these endless neologistic acronyms, ***but just so***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is agreeing with the person who wrote that urban dictionary definition.

If you read the full article, the author claims that "radical feminists" are seeking to deny transgender women the right to be recognised as women.

The phrase "just so" means "exactly right". For example, Kipling's "Just so" stories were stories that he told at bedtime to his daughter. He told the same stories over and over, until his daughter knew them word-for-word. The stories had to be told "Just so". If Kipling made a mistake his daughter would notice and complain.

The author of the article doesn't like the acronym "TERF" but thinks the definition is exactly right, or "just so".